# Make a Java application invisible to a user

Tags: java, swing, jframe, trayicon, jwindow

I'm trying to figure out a way to make a Java application invisible to the user.

Basically just trying to remove [this](http://screensnapr.com/e/atyZkF.png)

[image: task bar icon] <- Image

How can this be done?

```
public class TransparentWindow extends JFrame {

public TransparentWindow() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void initComponents() {
    setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setResizable(false);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    System.setProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw", "true");
    WindowUtils.setWindowTransparent(this, true);
    WindowUtils.setWindowAlpha(this, 0.6f);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TransparentWindow().setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: If I recall correctly make the outermost window you show a JPanel instead of a JFrame.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I've edited my post with my current code.

Comment: This would be great for spyware and malware!  What is your use-case for having an app. run on the client's computer without them being aware of it?

Comment: @AndrewThompson see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372362/transparent-click-through-always-on-top-jframe

Comment: @his  Guessed right first time - 'spyware'.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Nooooo... just an assistent guide and quality monitoring system ;-).

Comment: @Andrew, let's hope that nobody tells the malware authors about languages other than Java! Then the flood gates would be open!

Comment: @JulianFondren Fortunately, Java applets and applications delivered to clients using Java Web Start either cannot be set completely invisible, or require the user to explicitly authorize the app. to do 'anything' (again, hardly 'invisible').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just seems to have found the answer, just put the line `setVisible(false);` into comments and you will see the actual program, UNCOMMENT the line to see no trace is left, as far as I can see, that the Java Program is running somewhere, until you won't add the icon to your system tray, manually. Moreover how to remove your Application from Task Manager that question still remains, though you can remove the said icon, as pointed by you in your question.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TransparentWindow extends JFrame 
{
    public TransparentWindow() 
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() 
    {
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setResizable(false);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setOpacity(0.8f);
        setSize(200, 200);
        //System.setProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw", "true");
        //WindowUtils.setWindowTransparent(this, true);
        //WindowUtils.setWindowAlpha(this, 0.6f);
        setVisible(true);
        setVisible(false);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "It is working!", "Guess : ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TransparentWindow tw = new TransparentWindow();
    }
}
```

Here is a snapshot of my desktop on running this program, see the taskbar

[image: JAVA APPLICATTION]

Comment: The screenshots shows legitimate uses for top-level windows without taskbar entries to the right.

Comment: @his : Beg your pardon, I couldn't understand you.

Comment: @nIcEcOw Haha, you don't say? the design of Porsche is UNIQUE in the world. I even can detect it by its bumper.

Answer (score 4):

Extend from `JWindow` insted of `JFrame`. (I did not test this on Windows 7 as I don't sit in front of a Windows box right now. It worked for XP and works for Unity, which surprised me.)

Comment: +1 it does work with Windows 7, this gave me an answer, as to how to make widgets, hehe :-)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no way to remove the task bar icon.